# How to import a signed SSL certificate using Bouncy Castle in C# (Mono/Xamarin)?

Tags: c#, ssl, mono, xamarin, bouncycastle

I used Bouncy Castle to generate a private key, as well as a PKCS10 CSR, which I then send to a remote server to be signed. I get back a standard base64 encoded signed SSL certificate in response as a string. The question is, how do I import the signed certificate from a string, and then save both the private key and signed certificate as a PKCS12 (.PFX) file?

Additionally, how do I bundle in a CA certificate to be included within the PFX file?

```
// Generate the private/public keypair
RsaKeyPairGenerator kpgen = new RsaKeyPairGenerator ();
CryptoApiRandomGenerator randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator ();
kpgen.Init (new KeyGenerationParameters (new SecureRandom (randomGenerator), 2048));
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = kpgen.GenerateKeyPair ();

// Generate the CSR
X509Name subjectName = new X509Name ("CN=domain.com/name=Name");
Pkcs10CertificationRequest kpGen = new Pkcs10CertificationRequest ("SHA256withRSA", subjectName, keyPair.Public, null, keyPair.Private);
string certCsr = Convert.ToBase64String (kpGen.GetDerEncoded ());

// ** certCsr is now sent to be signed  **
// ** let's assume that we get "certSigned" in response, and also have the CA **
string certSigned = "[standard signed certificate goes here]";
string certCA = "[standard CA certificate goes here]";

// Now how do I import certSigned and certCA
// Finally how do I export everything as a PFX file?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bouncy Castle is a very powerful library, however the lack of documentation makes it quite difficult to work with. After searching for much too long through all of the classes and methods I finally found what I was looking for. The following code will take the previously generated private key, bundle it together with the signed certificate and the CA, and then save it as a .PFX file:

```
// Import the signed certificate
X509Certificate signedX509Cert = new X509CertificateParser ().ReadCertificate (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (certSigned));
X509CertificateEntry certEntry = new X509CertificateEntry (signedX509Cert);

// Import the CA certificate
X509Certificate signedX509CaCert = new X509CertificateParser ().ReadCertificate (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (certCA ));
X509CertificateEntry certCaEntry = new X509CertificateEntry (signedX509CaCert);

// Prepare the pkcs12 certificate store
Pkcs12Store store = new Pkcs12StoreBuilder ().Build ();

// Bundle together the private key, signed certificate and CA
store.SetKeyEntry (signedX509Cert.SubjectDN.ToString () + "_key", new AsymmetricKeyEntry (keyPair.Private), new X509CertificateEntry[] {
    certEntry,
    certCaEntry
});

// Finally save the bundle as a PFX file
using (var filestream = new FileStream (@"CertBundle.pfx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) {
    store.Save (filestream, "password".ToCharArray (), new SecureRandom ());
}
```

Feedback and improvements are welcome!

Comment: But do you need to have the CA cert or any intermediate certs to pull this off?